# powershell script to rework files

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a Source-File-1 and Source-File-2. The source file-1 has the following .CSV structure:

```
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;10;22;33;43;54;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;5;1.25;2.50;3.00;4;5.00;1.25;2.50;3.00;4;5.00;1.25;2.50;3.00;4;5.00;
```

The Source-File-1 can have a different number of lines. The number of line is based on the last value in the last column.

The source file-2 has the following .CSV structure:

```
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;10;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;22;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;33;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;43;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;54;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;
```

Now I would like via Powershell (Maybe that is possible?) to have the following target file.

```
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;10;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;TEST;1.25;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;22;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;TEST;2.50;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;33;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;TEST;3.00;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;43;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;TEST;4;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;54;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;TEST;5.00;
```

Is powershell the right one for this?

---

---

I have a CSV File with the following structure:

```
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;1A;2B;3B;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;5;1.00;2.00;3.00;4.00;5.00;6.00;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;
```

In column 26 you see the value 5 - there are 5 identical rows. Now I would like to have the following output: The values from the lines should then also be shifted -

```
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;1A;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;2B;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;3B;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;4;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;5;;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;
```

If you find in column 26 the value 10 you have the following output:

```
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;1A;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;2B;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;3B;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;4;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;5;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;6;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;7;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;8;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;9;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;10;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;
```

In addition the values from the columns from row 17 onwards should be added at the end:

```
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;1A;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;1.00;EUR;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;2B;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;2.00;EUR;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;3B;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;3.00;EUR;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;4;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;4.00;EUR;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;5;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;5.00;EUR;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;6;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;6.00;EUR;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;7;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;7;EUR;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;8;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;8;EUR;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;9;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;9;EUR;
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;VALUE8;VALUE9;VALUE10;10;;;;;;;;;;;;;;10;10;EUR;
```

How could I use Powershell for this?

Comment: The First CSV file structure is invalid to be imported with Powershell. You cannot have multiple column headers with same name in CSV, but you have them in source-1.csv.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. In the second part of the pst you will find a edit - so you could see my problem? How could i use powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should do the trick,

```
$col26
$tab1
$tab2

Get-Content .\Source-File-1.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $tab = $_  -split "(;)"

    $col26 = $tab[50]
    $tab1 = $tab[20..48]
    $tab2 = $tab[-31..-3]
}

$lineIdx = 0
Get-Content .\Source-File-2.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $tab = $_  -split "(;)"
    
    $newTab = $tab[0..19] + $tab1[$lineIdx*2] + $tab[19..100] + $tab2[$lineIdx*2] + {EUR;}

    Write-Host $newTab

    $lineIdx++;
}
```